# Issue with transforming data on insert?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I currently have some class

```
class Sha1(ColumnClause):
    pass

@compiles(Sha1)
def compile_sha1(element, compiler, **kw):
    return 'PASSWORD("{}")'.format(element.name)
```

And when I use SQLAlchemy orm to insert a column I can pass the attribute as Sha1(value) and let it do its thing.  However for testing purposes we load up our models into a database something like

```
insert = model.__table__.insert(values)
session.execute(insert)
```

Is there a way, in sqlalchemy, to override the way a specific model's sql is generated such that it will change the generated output from

```
insert into model (uuid, password) values (:uuid, :password)
```

to use my Sha1 class like

```
insert into model (uuid, password) values (:uuid, PASSWORD(:password))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer feature which allows this called `bind_expression()`. If i understand correctly, you probably want to change your `Sha1` to accept an arbitrary element, you'd no longer need to call `Sha1` explicitly, and in this case the argument would always be a `BindParam`:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class Sha1(ColumnElement):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

@compiles(Sha1)
def compile_sha1(element, compiler, **kw):
    return 'PASSWORD(%s)' % compiler.process(element.arg, **kw)


class Sha1Type(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return Sha1(bindvalue)

m = MetaData()
t = Table('mytable', m,

        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('password', Sha1Type)
    )


print t.insert()
print t.insert().values(password='some password')
```